# How to read Txt file section by section by special marker using Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, parsing, text

I am trying to use Pandas to analyze a text file output from s structural analysis software. 
The file has 24000+ lines which can be broken down into sections, with each of them starting by $, for example:

```
$ STORIES - IN SEQUENCE FROM TOP
  STORY "PLATFORM"  HEIGHT 51.9996 
  STORY "BULKHEAD"  HEIGHT 117 
  STORY "EMR"  HEIGHT 124.9992 
  STORY "Roof"  HEIGHT 140.0004 SIMILARTO "41st FL"  

$ GRIDS
  GRIDSYSTEM "G1"  TYPE "CARTESIAN"  BUBBLESIZE 60 
  GRID "G1"  LABEL "g"  DIR "X"  COORD -1068 VISIBLE "Yes"  BUBBLELOC "End"  
  GRID "G1"  LABEL "d"  DIR "X"  COORD -586 VISIBLE "Yes"  BUBBLELOC "End"  
  GRID "G1"  LABEL "d.3"  DIR "X"  COORD -460 VISIBLE "Yes"  BUBBLELOC "End"
```

I can use pd.read_csv and specify the skip_row parameter for each of them, but this is pretty repetitive and stupid when the text file is large.
Since the output file is quite well formatted, is there a way to parse the text file into sections by the headline of $..., and create a pd.dataframe for the lines below $...?

I would guess this is probably useful but I have to specify the number of txts:

```
marker = '$'
txt1, txt2, txt3, txt4 = txt.split(marker)
```

Also, am I able to specify a regex rule to marker?

Comment: In the examples of this file format that I have seen the numbers of items per line are constant for some types of lines but not all. For instance, STORY and GRID lines can each have the same numbers of items. MATERIAL PROPERTIES and FUNCTIONS do not. I can therefore see how the lines in a GRIDS section after GRIDSYSTEM could be parsed to be acceptable to Pandas but not the other sections I just mentioned. Would you just ignore the sections that really don't have a column structure that Pandas would expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the sections with the split function (and you don't have to specify the number of txts). The split function returns a list object. Each element of the list would represent a section.

```
sections = txt.split("$")
```

Now you can iterate through the list.

```
for actual_section in sections:
    print actual_section
```

For more information read the documentation about the split function [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split).